# Kapt exception when creating XML file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kapt

I am working in Kotlin on Android Studio.

The project compile and works perfectly, but then when I try to create a new XML file, I keep getting a kapt exception "Exception while annotation processing".

I try to create XML file by right click on res folder -> New -> Layout Resource File, and I also tried with right click on res folder -> New -> XML -> Layout XML File.

Here is my full project gradle :

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my full app gradle :

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.discodery.android.discoderyapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField 'Integer', 'RESTAURANT_ID', '1'
        }
    }
    /*
    productFlavors {
        dev {

        }
        prod {

        }
    }*/
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    //Permissions

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.hwangjr.rxbus:rxbus:1.0.5'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
    kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

I tried my best and I searched on the Internet to solve this error.
So my question is :
How can I create a XML file safely, without getting this error ?
Or, if that is not possible, how can I solved this Kapt exception ?

Thanks

Comment: Here are a few things I noticed that may or may not be related to your gradle issue:

1. Move `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to the top of your app gradle
2. You have two copies of `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`
3. `compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'` I'm not sure if you want the `@aar` in the version
4. I think you want `compile 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'` and `compile com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7`

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main")]
}
```

can you add this source set and try again? Kapt stubs compiler allows "generated" sources to be referenced from Kotlin otherwise the compiler will not be able to reference the missing sources.

edit: add this after

```
kapt {
  generateStubs = true
}
```

update:

try deleting `apply-plugin:'kotlin-kapt'`

and changing

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
    javacOptions {
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: I add this in the app gradle file after the kapt block, as you said, but I still have the same error:

[kapt] An exception occured: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Ecveption while annotation processing

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work, I now have some new compilations errors, I am fixing that and I will tell if it does work or not

Comment: Okay, it is taking more time than expected, I now have an "cannot access NonExistentClass" error. Thanks for the advices given so far, I will keep you in touch.

Comment: well I'd suggest commenting out any kap dependencies at this point https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10352

Answer (score 0):

Well,

After a lot of kapt exceptions and coming back to previous commits to avoir them, I think I found out some of the reasons one can have this error.

- You are using variables in your XML file that does not exists in your relative Kotlin file (thanks Copy/Paste)
- You forgot to close one of your tags

These answers are coming from my experience, I put them here in case of someone more newbie than me (hard to be) get this error, but I am sure there are more rational answers to that.

Thanks Ege for your kind help.